# How to (quickly) compile LaTeX in Vscode Workshop

Tags: vscode, latex-workshop

How do I quickly compile LaTeX in vscode workshop without having to go to the TeX tab everytime?

I know the `CTRL + ALT + B` hotkey but I can't select the recipe I want.

Answer (score 3):

**I. LaTeX Workshop way**

Go to `user settings (UI)` tab and search for `recipe:`, you will be able to see a section called `Latex-workshop > Latex > Recipe: Default`.

Change `first` to `last used`, then compile whatever recipe you need on the TeX menu, after that every compile you make using `CTRL + ALT + B` will be LuaLaTex.

**II. Code Runner way**

*I prefer this way because I like to use the mouse for compiling.*

The Code Runner extension allows people to compile a lot of file extension by using the right click menu, so here's how to use it with LaTeX:

1. First, download Code Runner from vscode extension tab.
2. Next, on the same page, click the little gear on the right of the
   uninstall button.
3. Then, click `Edit in settings.json` under `Executor Map by File Extension`
4. After that, add the following line before `.vb` or whatever comes first:

`".tex": "cd $dir && latexmk -lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1  $fileName"`

That's going to give you the exactly same thing as clicking the LuaLaTex button on the TeX menu.

You can change to `-xetex` or whatever you need.

In the end, the config should look like this:

```
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
        ".tex": "cd $dir && latexmk -lualatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 $fileName",
        ".vb": "cd $dir && vbc /nologo $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        ".vbs": "cscript //Nologo",
        ".scala": "scala",
        ".jl": "julia",
        ".cr": "crystal",
        ...
```

Now whenever you right click a LaTeX file you should be able to use the `Run Code` option.

Answer (score 0):

If your recipe uses LuaLaTeX, you could also install the [LaTeX Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjpvs.latex-previewer) extension alongside Workshop.

It has a keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+L to preview and also re-complies on save when the preview window is open.